# Function to prompt user for input

Tags: c, io

The following program calls a function, which prompts the user for input.  The function then returns one of three enum constants; `INPUT_SUCCESSFUL`, `INPUT_TOOLONG`, or `INPUT_FAILED`.  If successful, it prints the text entered by the user.  Otherwise, it prints an error message, and takes the appropriate action.

The function contains three parameters.  The first one is a constant character array, which gets passed the text that will be used to prompt the user.  The second is a character array, in which the text entered by the user will be placed.  And the third is the size of the character array.

I have the following questions...

1) Would it have been better to let the called function handle the printing of error messages, exiting the program, etc, instead of the main function?

2) Would it have been better to pass a pointer to the function so that it could allocate the appropriate memory, instead of passing it a fixed array?

3) Any potential issues with the program or improvements that can be made to the code?

The program was compiled as follows...

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.c user_input.c
```

...and received only warnings about unused parameters `argc` and `argv`.  Here are the files...

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "user_input.h"

#define MAX_STR_LEN 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char user_input[MAX_STR_LEN + 2]; /* +2 for newline character (\n) and terminating null character (\0) */
    input_status status;

    while (1)
    {
        status = get_user_input("Enter your name: ", user_input, sizeof(user_input));

        if (status == INPUT_FAILED)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read user input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (status == INPUT_TOOLONG)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Entry exceeds %d characters\n", MAX_STR_LEN);
            continue;
        }

        if (strlen(user_input) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Entry is missing\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (user_input[0] == 0x18) /* user entered Ctrl+X (^x) to cancel */
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "User cancelled\n");
            return 0;
        }

        break;
    }

    printf("User entered:  %s\n", user_input);

    return 0;
}
```

**user_input.h**

```
#ifndef USER_INPUT_H
    #define USER_INPUT_H

    typedef enum
    {
        INPUT_SUCCESSFUL,
        INPUT_TOOLONG,
        INPUT_FAILED
    } input_status;

    void flush_input();

    input_status get_user_input(const char *prompt, char *user_input, size_t size);

#endif
```

**user_input.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "user_input.h"

void flush_input()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        /* skip it */ ;
}

input_status get_user_input(const char *prompt, char *user_input, size_t size)
{
    printf("%s", prompt);

    if (fgets(user_input, size, stdin) == NULL)
        return INPUT_FAILED;

    char *pNewline;
    if ((pNewline = strchr(user_input, '\n')) == NULL)
    {
        flush_input();
        return INPUT_TOOLONG;
    }

    *pNewline = '\0';

    return INPUT_SUCCESSFUL;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems fairly sane; I only picked up a couple of things:

### Don't ignore `errno`

You do check for failure, which is good; but you ignore `errno`. You should use it, and/or `perror`, to get more detailed failure information.

### Assign-in-condition

There's not a compelling reason to do this:

```
char *pNewline;
if ((pNewline = strchr(user_input, '\n')) == NULL)
```

Just assign `pNewLine` where it's declared, not where it's used in the condition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `errno` - Do I check within the main function where I test for `status == INPUT_FAILED`?

Comment: `Assign-in-condition` - Is this considered poor programming practice?

Comment: By the way, I like your comment - `It seems fairly sane`.  :-)

Comment: Regarding `errno` - there are various strategies for this. One strategy is, rather than returning an enum, return `errno` itself, with 0 indicating no error. Or, you could check in the calling function what `errno` is if you've received a `FAILED`.

Comment: Regarding assignment-in-condition - yes, it's usually considered poor programming practice. It's confusing and prone to human error. In narrow contexts it can make the code more legible but usually it should be avoided.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: Regarding the assignment in conditions: it's common to have it in `while` loops, in order to avoid writing the same code twice. A typical example is `while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) { … }`. In `if` statements though, the condition is always evaluated once, so there's no need to squash it together into the same line of code.

Comment: @RolandIllig Oh, I see.  That's great, thank you very much.  Cheers!

Comment: "but you ignore `errno`" --> C does **not** require `errno` to be set with `fgets()`.  Portable code would not rely on `errno` being set to indicate an  I/O issue.

Answer (score 4):

- > 1) Would it have been better to let the called function handle the printing of error messages, exiting the program, etc, instead of the main function?

  It is always better to separate error handling from the rest of the code. But you could have placed the error handling in a separate function.

  Related to this, you could have created a more meaningful loop condition in the caller than `while(1)`. Also, the presence of `continue` in a C program is always "code smell"; it is a dead certain indication that a loop can be rewritten in better ways. There is a very sound programming rule saying that C code should never jump non-conditionally upwards - this applies to `continue` and `goto` both.

  For example you could create a separate function for error handling the type `input_status`, which could either be part of user_input.h/user_input.c, or defined in the caller, whatever makes most sense program design-wise.

  ```
  bool input_status_ok (input_status status)
  {
    if(status == INPUT_FAILED)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read user input\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      return false; // never executed but might block potential compiler warnings
    }
    if (status == INPUT_TOOLONG)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Entry exceeds %d characters\n", MAX_STR_LEN);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  ```

  (In case of a whole lot of different error codes, we could perhaps replace the `if` chain with a `switch`.)

  With that out of the way of your loop, you can have one loop checking the errors returned by the function, and another, outer loop for checking the data contents:

  ```
  bool user_cancel = false;

  while (!user_cancel)
  {
    do 
    {
      status = get_user_input("Enter your name: ", user_input, sizeof(user_input));
    } while( !input_status_ok(status) );

    if (user_input[0] == CANCEL) /* user entered Ctrl+X (^x) to cancel */
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "User cancelled\n");
      user_cancel = true;
    }
  }
  ```

  We've now separated error handling of the function result from error handling of the data contents. There are no icky non-conditional branches and the code is overall easier to read.
- > 2) Would it have been better to pass a pointer to the function so that it could allocate the appropriate memory, instead of passing it a fixed array?

  No, it is always better to leave allocation to the caller when you have that option. That way, you separate memory allocation from algorithm which is better program design - meaning your function will only do its designated task, and it won't care if the memory used is allocated statically, on the stack or on the heap.

---

> 3) Any potential issues with the program or improvements that can be made to the code?

- Avoid "magic numbers" - add something like `#define CANCEL 0x18u` instead of using the magic number 0x18 in the middle of the code.
- Never write functions with an empty parenthesis for the parameter list in C, such as `void flush_input()`. This is obsolete style and has poor type safety, since it means "function that accepts any parameters". C is different from C++ here, in C++ the empty parenthesis is encouraged and equivalent to `(void)`.
- Avoid assignment inside conditions. This is problematic for many reasons:

  - Assignments introduce an extra side-effect that might have dependencies in relation to the right-hand side of the assignment.
  - The classic == vs = bug. All modern compiler can check for this, but if you never write = inside conditions you don't need to worry. (Better yet, you won't have to deal with people who's been living under a rock since the 1980s and therefore still suggest that you should use the unreadable [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) )
  - Mashing as many operations as possible into a single line makes the code harder to read.

  Instead, simply write:

  ```
  char *pNewline = strchr(user_input, '\n');
  if (pNewline == NULL)
  ```
- You should place all library `#includes` in the h file. This documents all library dependencies to the user of your code, who should only need to read the public h file.

Comment: Lundin, this is absolutely fantastic, great insight.  I can't wait to implement everyone of your suggestions and follow your advice.  Thank you so much for all your help.  I really appreciate it.  And I like your comment "...living under a rock since the 1980s...". :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrect test**

Not finding a `'\n'` is a "too long a line" when `strlen(user_input) + 1 == size`

```
// not quite the right test
if ((pNewline = strchr(user_input, '\n')) == NULL) {
    flush_input();
    return INPUT_TOOLONG;
}
```

Not finding a `'\n'` can occur when that was all that was left in `stdin` and end-of-file occurred without the last character as a `'\n'`.

```
size_t size_used = strlen(user_input) + 1;
if (size_used == size) {
    flush_input();
    return INPUT_TOOLONG;
}
```

Advanced issue not handled: Not finding a `'\n'` can occur when a *null character* was read as `strchr(user_input, '\n')` stops at the read *null character* and not the appended one.

**Spinning CPU cycles**

No need to run down the length of the string to find it length.  Simply test first element.

```
// if (strlen(user_input) == 0)
if (user_input[0] == 0)
```

Comment: my apologies for not getting back to you sooner, for some reason I didn't get a notification of your reply, and so I didn't see your post until today.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but I'm having trouble understanding why checking for '\n' would fail.  Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Domenic "why checking for '\n' would fail" --> 1) line longer than `sizeof(user_input)` or 2) input consisted  of a `'\0'` before the `'\n'`.

Comment: That's great, thank you for your help, I really appreciate it, cheers!